# VHDL shift or rotate: difference between concatenation and builtin functions (sll, sra,...)

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

When you want to implement a shift/rotate operation in VHDL you can use either concatenation or built-in function of VHDL such as sll, sra, ror. Now my question is: what is the difference between the two (if there is one), both in terms of simulation performance (if applicable) and in particular in terms of synthesis results?

In my opinion concatenation could provide some advantages because it's just a matter of moving wires, while I don't know how built-in functions are treated by the synthesizer. But I am not totally certain and I'd like to understand which one is the best.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Arithmetic and logical shifts and rotates are done with functions in VHDL, not operators](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/bit-shifts-in-vhdl.html) ,"You've come to this page because you've asked about shift operators in VHDL".  Concatenation should certainly be more compact.

Comment: That's a nice reading, but it's also instructive to read Chapter 4.8 - Shift Operations from [VHDL-2008 - Just the New Stuff](http://www.amazon.com/VHDL-2008-Stuff-Systems-Silicon/dp/0123742498) for an update to the whole story.

Comment: And who supports the -2008 versions for synthesis? "VHDL-2008 extends the definitions of shift operations to include sla and sra in numeric_bit and numeric_std. It also defines all of the shift operations in the new arithmetic packages numeric_bit_unsigned, numeric_std_unsigned, and in the fixed-point packages (see Chapter 8). In all cases, the overloaded sla and sra operators on signed values have the same numeric behavior as the shift_left and shift_right functions."

Comment: Ok, so never use the built-in functions, rather use shift_left(), shift_right(), rotate_left(), and rotate_right(). But now, the question is the same, are there advantages/disadvantages in using concatenation with respect to concatenation?

For instance I don't want the synthesizer to instantiate a shift register to make a constant shift. This is clearly avoided if I use concatenation, but is it the case also for those functions?

Thanks

Comment: @mike - Look at the underlying functions (XSRA etc.) none appear to use loops (which implies parallelism, not repetitive operations) nor is there a clock involved. There is likely no synthesis disadvantage to using shift_left, etc. Concatenation operators are predefined for single dimension array types and likely to simulate faster and generally needed as well unless dealing with a single fixed width array right hand operand or a slice left hand assignment target, in which case you likely have an additional assignment statement.  Say, you can do away with either with a constant shift...